# ESP8266-12F trouble

Tags: esp8266, arduino-esp8266, firmware

Some time ago, I was using my Esp8266-12F module (concretely I was using a Wemos D1 mini). At that time, everything was running perfectly, but when I try it again, both of my modules were not working as expected.
Then, I remembered that I had similar trouble while I was working on it, so I just decided to do what worked the time before.
I restored the firmware as I did, but instead of working, it keeps doing the same thing. The modules (both) keep their LEDs blinking and sending some message. In this message, the modules send weird characters, but one part is readable, and it says something like "DISCONNECTED".

For restoring the firmware I'm using the Esptool with:

`esptool.py write_flash --flash_size 2MB-c1 0x0 boot_v1.7.bin 0x01000 at/1024+1024/user1.2048.new.5.bin 0x1fb000 blank.bin 0x1fc000 esp_init_data_default_v08.bin 0xfe000 blank.bin 0x1fe000 blank.bin` from the AT 1.7.4.

When I flash it using the Esptool, it returns:

[image]

After flashing it, I cannot interact with the module, the only thing is that the less starts blinking periodically.

Does someone know what can I do? I mean, I have tried exactly the same I did once ago, but now it's not working.

Comment: This question is more suitable for [arduino.se], as it is not programming related.

Comment: do you have the Serial Monitor at 115200 baud?

Comment: @Juraj I have tried talking to the module at different baud rates, but I receive understandable feedback when I reset the module due to the button (only if the sketch and serial monitor are working at 74880 bauds). I have also uploaded that it returns to me when I flash it to the post. Thanks againg.

Comment: use 115200 baud to see the startup messages of AT firmware. clear the flash with esptool, then flash the AT firmware again. if it doesn't work, try to add `--flash-mode dout` to AT firmware flashing command

Comment: @Juraj i tryed what you said, but it still doesn't work. I have put `esptool.py write_flash --flash_mode dout --flash_size 2MB-c1 0x0 boot_v1.7.bin 0x01000 at/1024+1024/user1.2048.new.5.bin 0x1fb000 blank.bin 0x1fc000 esp_init_data_default_v08.bin 0xfe000 blank.bin 0x1fe000 blank.bin` (everythong with the respective directions into my pc). I have try it at 115200 bauds.

Comment: @Juraj the sketch I'm using to test the module its: `#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial wifi(8,9);
#define baud 115200
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(baud);
  wifi.begin(baud);
}
void loop() {
   if(wifi.available()){
    Serial.write(wifi.read());
  }
    if(Serial.available()){
      wifi.write(Serial.read());   
  }
}`